# Query Formula error (Getting data from one sheet, some of it have indentions)

Tags: function, google-sheets

I am having a problem in my query formula. I need to transfer the journal to ledger but credited account (with indentions) are not appearing on the ledger. I am using query, and some formulas to get the balance, but I can't get it right.

Please see the attached link for google sheet.

The Ledger have the query formula, but not successful. On the desired output, I put it all manually to show the desired result.

Thank you so much!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MCYgu86qunb2tIZTOeoOrn876jAKbFKXUT-pE6a_gDM/edit?usp=sharing

Feel free to ask me questions if there are some confusion. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`Query()` doesn't like a mix of column values but `filter()` may work better.

Something like this in cell `Ledger!A6`:

```
=filter({Journal!A:A,Journal!C:F},Journal!B:B=B2)
```

However, to replicate your 'Desired Output', you'll need to add value in the missing cells, like dates and 'Paid up start-up cost'.

Then your formula in Col F needs fixing, someting like this in cell `Ledger!F6` (deleting all values below):

```
=arrayformula(if(A6:A<>"",sumif(row(D6:D),"<="&row(D6:D),D6:D)-sumif(row(E6:E),"<="&row(E6:E),E6:E),))
```